# Implement search and filtering functionality for Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I create application in spring boot using the postgress database.

I want to implement the search functionality by title and filtering by article categories but i dont know where to start. For now, the application allows you to display all the results of the table.

What should I start with? Thank you in advance for your help and all comments.

**Model:**

```
@Entity(name="articles")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Articles {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long article_id;
private String title;
private String issn;
private String eissn;
private String title2;
private String issn2;
private String eissn2;
private Integer points;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "articles_categories",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "article_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"))
private List<Category> categories;

public Long getArticle_id() {
    return article_id;
}

public void setArticle_id(Long article_id) {
    this.article_id = article_id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getIssn() {
    return issn;
}

public void setIssn(String issn) {
    this.issn = issn;
}

public String getEissn() {
    return eissn;
}

public void setEissn(String eissn) {
    this.eissn = eissn;
}

public String getTitle2() {
    return title2;
}

public void setTitle2(String title2) {
    this.title2 = title2;
}

public String getIssn2() {
    return issn2;
}

public void setIssn2(String issn2) {
    this.issn2 = issn2;
}

public String getEissn2() {
    return eissn2;
}

public void setEissn2(String eissn2) {
    this.eissn2 = eissn2;
}

public Integer getPoints() {
    return points;
}

public void setPoints(Integer points) {
    this.points = points;
}

public List<Category> getCategories() {
    return categories;
}

public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
    this.categories = categories;
}

public Articles(){

}}
```

**Repository:**

```
public interface ArticlesRepository extends JpaRepository<Articles,Long> {
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/articles")
public class ArticlesController {


private ArticleService articleService;

@Autowired
public void setArticleService(ArticleService articleService) {
    this.articleService = articleService;
}

@GetMapping 
public String getAll(Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("articles", articleService.list());
    return "articles"; 
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Service
public class ArticleService {


@Autowired
private ArticlesRepository articlesRepository;

public ArticleService() {
}

public List<Articles> list(){
    return articlesRepository.findAll();
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#specifications), [JpaSpecificationExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html) to filter/search your articles,

**Respoitory**,

```
interface ArticlesRepository extends JpaRepository<Articles, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Articles> {   
}
```

**Controller method**,

```
@GetMapping
public List<Articles> list(@RequestParam int size, @RequestParam int page, @RequestParam string search, Model model){     
    Page<Articles> pageableArticales = articlesRepository.findAll(searchArticleSpecification(search), PageRequest.of(page, limit);
    return pageableArticales.getContent();
}}
```

> Note: learn to create specifications and write `searchArticleSpecification(search)` method which provides you `Specification<Articles>` based on your search logics.

Comment: In my project articles dont have author field- why is this field needed in this case? I want to implement such functionality which create me the possibility to write words in search field( for example 'many') and then records which containing this word('many') will be visible on the page.